# How do I use tensorflow models to give exact coordinates of the prediction in react.js

Tags: reactjs, tensorflow, object-detection

I m using tensorflow to predict what object is there. however, it gives the coordinates in such a way that I can draw a rectangle with it. I want it such that I can draw a irregular object with it like it should cover the whole object without any excess area.

Code:

```
export const drawRect = (detections, ctx) =>{
    // Loop through each prediction
    detections.forEach(prediction => {
        
      // Extract boxes and classes
      const [x, y, width, height] = prediction['bbox']; 
      const text = prediction['class']; 
  
      // Set styling
      const color = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#' + color
      ctx.font = '18px Arial';
  
      // Draw rectangles and text
      ctx.beginPath();   
      ctx.fillStyle = '#' + color
      ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
      ctx.rect(x, y, width, height); 
      ctx.stroke();
    });
  }
```

The output is a rectangle box on each of predictions. However, I want it in a irregular manner like all around the object in a irregular shape.

Comment: Please, provide an example of your output and the expected output as well.